# CMD opening and closing?

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

from time to time recently I notice the cmd window opening and then immediately closing. I need to find out what is using it.

windows 7. updated.

Answer (score 1):

Some program is running in the background. I would start by looking at recently installed programs. If you haven't, then look at your web browser and see if you've might have gotten had an update.

I actually found this odd behavior on my chrome due to to:

infinity tab

Which is a really nice browser extension that got hacked. Once removed, it stopped my issues.

You could also look into:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/

Which has a lot of specialized programs such as process monitor to see you see what is starting a program. Most likely you'll be looking at Process Explorer and Process Monitor.